# How to implement Outside Click in React? (with a twist)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My team has been using this function to monitor clicks outside of a DIV:

```
function useOutsideClick(ref: any, onClickOut: () => void, deps: Array<mixed> = []) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = ({ target }: any) => !ref?.contains(target) && onClickOut?.();
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, deps);
}
```

This has generally worked well for us but recently a colleague encountered a situation that did not work:

```
<div id='outerContainer'>
  <div id='collapsedContainer'>
    // Collapsed content here
  </div>
  <div id='expandedContainer'>
    // Expanded content here
  </div>
</div>
```

My colleague added a reference to `collapsedContainer` and it worked as expected ... in that clicking outside the bounds of `collapsedContainer` causes the `useOutsideClick` event handler to fire.

But a problem arises when actions cause the `expandedContainer` to appear.  Then nothing worked properly with `useOutsideClick`.

I investigated the issue and tried adding `ref` properties to `outerContainer` and `expandedContainer` but things just didn't work as expected.  I'm not sure what was going on.

If you were faced with the use case, what solution would you propose?

Robert

Comment: You mention "then nothing worked properly". What wasn't working properly exactly? What does the component look like which uses the `useOutsideClick` event?